# Blazor WASM application stops responding after handling modal ok eventcallback, which performs a delete request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, blazor-webassembly, ant-blazor

I implemented a delete button for a table, and when clicking the button a modal is shown to make sure the user really wants to delete that entry, but after the ok button is clicked, the application stops responding. This only happens if I both delete and then get the data from the database using http request to my ASP.NET REST API.

Here are the relevant codes:

```
 @code{
    private async Task HandleCinemaModalOk(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        visibleCinemaModal = false;
        var deleteResponse = await httpClient.DeleteAsync($"list_movies/{deleteableMovieId}");
        movies = await MoviesClient.GetMovies();
    }
 }
```

MoviesClient:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Movie>> GetMovies() =>
            await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<Movie>>("list_movies");
```

HTML part:

```
@*Extra column for edit and delete*@
    <AntDesign.Column Width="300" @bind-Field="@context.Id" Title="">
        @{
            deleteableMovieId = @context.Id;
        }
        <Button type="danger" @onclick="@(() => visibleCinemaModal = true )" icon="delete">
        </Button>
        <Modal Title="Delete Movie"
               Visible="visibleCinemaModal"
               OnOk="HandleCinemaModalOk"
               OnCancel="HandleCinemaModalCancel">
            <Text>Are you sure you want to delete @context.Title ?</Text>
        </Modal>

        <Button type="primary" @onclick="@(() => NavigationManager.NavigateTo(@$"/editmovie/{context.Id}" ))" icon="edit">
        </Button>

    </AntDesign.Column>
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Movie>>> GetMovies()
        {
            return await _db.Movies.ToListAsync();
        }


        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        [Route("list_movies/{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<int>> DeleteMovieById(int id)
        {
            var movie = await _db.Movies.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            _db.Movies.Remove(movie);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok(movie);
        }
```

So if I don't add the line `movies = await MoviesClient.GetMovies();` the application doesn't freeze, but it's not an option, because the UI must update to show the user that the deletion was successful.

After a long wait, I get the following error in the console:

> ```
> fail: Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.DevToolsProxy[0] DevToolsProxy::Run: Exception System.AggregateException: One or more
> ```
>
> errors occurred. (The remote party closed the WebSocket connection
> without completing the close handshake.)  --->
> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The remote
> party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close
> handshake.    at
> System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ThrowIfEOFUnexpected(Boolean
> throwOnPrematureClosure)    at
> System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.EnsureBufferContainsAsync(Int32
> minimumRequiredBytes, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean
> throwOnPrematureClosure)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16
> token)    at
> System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ReceiveAsyncPrivate[TResult](Memory`1 payloadBuffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.ValueTaskSourceAsTask.<>c.<.cctor>b__4_0(Object
> state) --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at
> Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.DevToolsProxy.ReadOne(WebSocket
> socket, CancellationToken token)    --- End of inner exception stack
> trace ---    at
> Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.DevToolsProxy.Run(Uri browserUri,
> WebSocket ideSocket)

Edit:

It turned out that the problem was that I've put the modal inside a column, and when I clicked on the delete icon, it opened a modal for each record, but the ok button closed the "wrong" modal, and the EventCallback couldn't return.

Comment: my idea on it is that you may combine 2 requests into one. And do not `return Ok()` but return an object which contained the deleted id and the movie list.

Comment: Interesting idea, but it still didn't solve my problem. I've also noticed, that after clicking on the Ok button, the browser starts using more and more memory even up until 5 GB of ram, so there must be a memory leak or something like that somewhere. I hope it may give another idea to someone on how to solve the issue. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Movie>>> GetMovies()
    {
        var l= await _db.Movies.ToListAsync();
        return Ok(l);

    }
```

you're not returning an ActionResult, so I bet it's getting caught up doing a database call, try changing to code above.

Similarly, from your delete action you're returning ActionResult not ActionResult. Change that to return Ok(0) (if you client is expecting an int, or change the signiture to ActionResult).

Finally, I suspect you don't want to be awaiting the db save changes call, you actually want to wait for it.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the controller methods, but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Ok, That leaves the most likely culprits that the DB call isn't completing. Have your tried putting some break points on your controller methods? Especially the delete method, does it come back and return something?

Comment: I've tried it, everything seems to be working when using breakpoint. The interesting thing is, that if I put a breakpoint at movies = await MoviesClient.GetMovies(); at the end of the HandleCinemaModalOk eventcallback, and try to delete a movie, it obviously stops due to the breakpoint and when I hit continue in the visual studio debugger, it works fine. If I just run it without breakpoints, it remains the same and stops responding.